# Validate JavaFX form only after submission using ValidationSupport

Tags: java, forms, validation, javafx, controlsfx

I'm trying to validate a javafx form using ValidationSupport, the validation is working, but when I access the form the "errors decorations" are already shown, even before the form is submitted or the textfield is focused.

```
ValidationSupport validationSupport = new ValidationSupport();
    validationSupport.registerValidator(textField, Validator.createEmptyValidator("Text is required"));
```

The following image shows an example of the form in its initial state.

[image: My Form]

How can I force the decoration to show only after the user submit the form or change the TextField value?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To validate controls on demand is an issue ([on-demand validation option](https://github.com/controlsfx/controlsfx/issues/226)) on ControlsFx's issue tracker which is still open so ControlsFx does NOT support it yet.

But there is a way to suppress error decorations:

```
ValidationSupport validationSupport = new ValidationSupport();
validationSupport.setErrorDecorationEnabled(false);
```

Later, when you actually want to validate (on submit button for example) you need to reset it to default value:

```
validationSupport.setErrorDecorationEnabled(true);
validationSupport.redecorate();
```

This way, fields still get validated by every change but error decorations are not shown until you actually want them to be shown.

---

### Example:

In this example we'd like to see validation errors only if number field has the focus.

```
public class Sandbox extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        GridPane pane = new GridPane();
        pane.add(new Label("Number field:"), 0 , 0);
        TextField numberField = new TextField("");
        pane.add(numberField, 1, 0);
        TextField textField = new TextField("");
        pane.add(new Label("Text field:"), 0, 1);
        pane.add(textField, 1, 1);

        ValidationSupport vs = new ValidationSupport();
        vs.setErrorDecorationEnabled(false); // we don't want errors to bother us for now.
        vs.registerValidator(numberField, Validator.createRegexValidator("must be digits only!", "\\d*", Severity.ERROR));

        // validate and show errors only if number field has the focus
        vs.errorDecorationEnabledProperty().bind(numberField.focusedProperty());

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(pane));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(Sandbox.class);
    }
}
```

or if you want to see validation errors only after submit button is clicked for the first time:

```
        ...
        Button button = new Button("Submit");
        pane.add(button, 0, 2);

        ValidationSupport vs = new ValidationSupport();
        vs.setErrorDecorationEnabled(false); // we don't want errors to bother us for now.
        vs.registerValidator(numberField, Validator.createRegexValidator("must be digits only!", "\\d*", Severity.ERROR));

        
        button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                vs.setErrorDecorationEnabled(true); // validate and show errors now!
            }
        });
        ...
```

Comment: This does not do anything. How am I supposed to do what the op wants? I binded the enable / redecorate to a button but nothing happens when I click it.

Comment: I don't know what boolean property on your button you binded `errorDecorationEnabledProperty` to, but generally you should perform `setErrorDecorationEnabled(true)` when some condition is met. I added two examples.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at ValidatorFX, which tries to overcome some of the problems with validation in ControlsFX.
Full disclosure: I am the author auf ValidatorFX.