# ControlsFX: Validation on Button click

Tags: validation, javafx, controlsfx

I am trying to validate two `Textfield`s in javafx on a button click, I am using ControlsFX to do this. Here is my validation code:

```
private void applyValidationSupprot() {
    ValidationSupport support = new ValidationSupport();

    support.registerValidator(userName, false, (Control control, String value) ->
            ValidationResult.fromErrorIf(userName, "Required", isValid)
    );
    support.registerValidator(password, false, (Control control, String value) ->
            ValidationResult.fromErrorIf(password, "Required", isValid)
    );
}
```

`userName` and `password` are my `Textfield`s and `isValid` is a variable declared previously, and my button's `onAction` event is bound to this method:

```
public void validate() {
    isValid = true;
}
```

But when I click the button the validation do not happen. Where is the problem?

Reminder: I do not how to make validation with `createEmptyValidator` but I want my validation to happen on my button click.

Comment: ControlsFx does not support on-demand validation. If you're trying to suppress error messages shown on every text change event and trigger them on button click, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41603284/validate-javafx-form-only-after-submission-using-validationsupport) post.

Comment: good. why don't you add this as an answer